# WPF Button Automatic Dimension in Style with background image

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to create a style for buttons in WPF and the nature of button is like it shows a background image and on mouse over it shows a different background image.
I created the below xaml structure for this

```
 <Style x:Key="ShelfRefreshButton" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="22"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="21"/>    
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="images\refresh_active.png" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border Name="border" 
                            BorderThickness="0" 
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="images\refresh_mouseover.png" />
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>

                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

The problem i am facing is Width and Height in the Style . How can we make it to auto? The button should resize according to image size . So no need to set Width and Height hard coded values .
In the above xaml style if i remove the Width and Height Properties button i snot visible at all. How to solve this issue?What changes i need to apply on the Style?

Answer (score 1):

Using ImageBrush is a little tricky, I would suggest you to create new Image element, and control that. Put Image and ContentPresenter into Grid. Next, give name to Image, then you can control it. After that, make sure you set Image to NoResize and bind Button Width&Height to Image's ActualWidth & ActualHeight.